# Data organization

Tags: predictive-modeling

I want to model road accidents using Random Forest and Neural Networks, and predict where (Km) will the next accident occur. I chose 5 variables titles (each variable affects accidents) at the top of the 5 columns, under which I will enter the data. There will be a 6th column containing the km where accident have taken place in the past corresponding to the variables I chose.

My question is pretty simple: I do not know, where will the results appear? Where will the Outcome (km of the next accident) be shown? Thank you for any help

Comment: Welcome to the site @Etzel. You questions is quite unclear. Can you rephrase your question and explain what you already have and what you dont have yet?

Comment: I am looking to model this data using Random Forest and Neural networks. My confusion is because I do not see how the result (Outcome) is shown after training and modeling the data provided. in which km I expect the next road accident To happen, based on the modeled data, and the accuracy to be expected . Do I get one result? More than one? I have looked up Orange's tutorials on Youtube....but I have not seen this issue addressed.

I work with stochastic simulation and hybrid complex systems, but the procedure is straightforward. I am really interested in learning how to work with orange.